# Lightbox2 doesn't appear in the page

Tags: 7

I want to add Lightbox2 from http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ to my page, but following instructions (adding a JavaScript, and a CSS file) doesn't work.

I thought I did all correctly, but when I click on the image, it doesn't show any popup.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: You're using a version of lightbox that requires jQuery 1.7, whereas Drupal comes with jQuery 1.4 by default. Try the dev version of [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update), or [jQuery Multi](http://drupal.org/project/jqmulti). Either of those should let you load the right version of jQuery into the page.

Comment: That seems an acceptable answer. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

There's also a [Lightbox2 Drupal Module](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) that integrates with various other modules. And you don't need to update your Drupal's jQuery.

[Here's the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/144469) since I don't really know how you're intending to use Lightbox2 on your website.